# HP Envy AH0003na touchscreen not working on Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: hp, touchscreen

I am new to Linux and I have Ubuntu nearly set up on my laptop. The only issue I need to solve is getting the touchscreen to work. It is not detected at all in `xinput` or `touchegg`.

I found this GitHub project which is achieving what I want to achieve. It is, however, too incomplete and too complicated for me. https://github.com/dmoisset/hp-envy13

How do I make the touchscreen work in Ubuntu or is there another distro that it will work with? I can try anything as I have nothing to lose

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and HP have refused to help.

This is the output of xinput:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wide Vision HD Camera: HP Wi           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP Wireless hotkeys                       id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

This is the output of lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0781:5591 SanDisk Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b655 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 0):

as to your last question, Peppermint 8 and 9, as well as Zorin OS supported my touch screen without any action on my part. Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS and Mint act like it's just a screen. I have a Dell E6430 ATG, not an HP, but still trying to make it work with Ubuntu too. I'm still looking for answers.